# Windows 10 activation on Dell laptops

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation, dell-xps

Having a Windows 10 activation issue which I think is specific to Dell laptops.
Did a clean windows 10 install on my Dell XPS 15.
Under settings-Activation there is an error which says

> Activation failed because this device doesn't have a valid digital
>   entitlement or product key. Error code 0x803F7001

Ok so then I retrieved my product key from BIOS and tried the 'Change Product Key' option.
After entering the key I get a new error

> We couldn't activate Windows 
>   Error Code 0xc004f014

So what gives. Why is this so difficult?
I used both a 3rd party tool and a command line option to retrieve my product key so fairly sure its accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after clean installing `Windows 10 Home Single Language (Version 1511)` on my dell inspiron 3542.

When I contacted Microsoft Support, they told me :

> Windows 10 is a **free upgrade**. You have to **upgrade** to Windows
>   10. Windows 10 will automatically get activated after few days. You have to **upgrade**. Cleanly installed Windows 10 **can not be
>   activated** with Win 7/8/8.1 keys.

This is what they have on their website :

> Starting with the November update, Windows 10 (Version 1511) can be
>   activated using some Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1 product
>   keys. For more info, see the section Activating Windows 10 (Version
>   1511 or higher) using a Windows 7, Windows 8, or Windows 8.1 product
>   key in this topic.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-10/activation-in-windows-10)

Notice the line :

> Starting with the November update, Windows 10 (Version 1511) **can be
>   activated using some** Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1 product
>   keys.

Those **some keys** do not include oem product keys.

[image]

So the only way to get genuine Windows 10 on computers with oem keys (at least on dell) is to upgrade.

I had no other choice so I upgraded to Windows 10 and it got activated within 2 days with a valid digital entitlement.

Comment: The very first type of key that is supported, are **OEM Windows 8** keys, I don't understand this answer.  **It is flat out wrong.**

Comment: You are mistaken.  Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 OEM machines do not have COA stickers (they do have a sticker just not one with the license on it).  They 3 only have keys embedded in firmware.  I know for a face, because of personal direct experience with these types of machines, your answer is wrong.  I left a comment as a courtesy  The other words "COA" for those devices is a digital one.  There are lots of reason Single Language would have problem activating, if you submitted your question, we could have helped figure it out.

Comment: I don't live in a region where Single Language is even sold.  I know from the hundred plus questions on Single Language that people even have problems going from 8.0 to 8.1 due to them using different languages.

Answer (score -1):

More than likely you are upgrading to a different version, which is not allowed. Example, Home versions can only be upgraded to W10 Home.

Language options can also cause this if changed from original.

[More](http://More%20than%20likely%20you%20are%20upgrading%20to%20a%20different%20version,%20which%20is%20not%20allowed...http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/4997/t/19668715)